# Row_Number simulation in Sql server 2000

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have a sample input table as

```
Declare  @input TABLE(Name VARCHAR(8))
INSERT INTO @input(Name)  values('Aryan') 
INSERT INTO @input(Name)  values('Aryan') 
INSERT INTO @input(Name)  values('Joseph') 
INSERT INTO @input(Name)  values('Vicky') 
INSERT INTO @input(Name)  values('Jaesmin') 
INSERT INTO @input(Name)  values('Aryan') 
INSERT INTO @input(Name)  values('Jaesmin') 
INSERT INTO @input(Name)  values('Vicky') 
INSERT INTO @input(Name)  values('Padukon') 
INSERT INTO @input(Name)  values('Aryan') 
INSERT INTO @input(Name)  values('Jaesmin') 
INSERT INTO @input(Name)  values('Vick') 
INSERT INTO @input(Name)  values('Padukon') 
INSERT INTO @input(Name)  values('Joseph') 
INSERT INTO @input(Name)  values('Marya') 
INSERT INTO @input(Name)  values('Vicky')
```

Also I have a tally table as under

```
declare @t table(n int)
insert into @t select 1 union all select 2 union all
select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all
select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all
select 9 union all select 10 union all select 11 union all
select 12 union all select 13 union all select 14 union all
select 15 union all select 16 union all select 17 union all
select 18 union all select 19 union all select 20
```

In Sql Server 2005 if I do as

```
 Select rn, name from (
    select ROW_NUMBER()over (order by Name) as rn , * from @input) x
    where rn % 2 <> 0
```

I get the output as

```
rn  name
1   Aryan
3   Aryan
5   Jaesmin
7   Jaesmin
9   Joseph
11  Padukon
13  Vick
15  Vicky
```

Bu I am restricted to Sql server 2000. How can I get the same output?

I have tried with

```
SELECT name, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @input AS i2 WHERE i2.Name <= i1.Name) As rn
FROM @input AS i1
```

but the output is wrong

```
name    rn
Aryan   4
Aryan   4
Joseph  9
Vicky   16
Jaesmin 7
Aryan   4
Jaesmin 7
Vicky   16
Padukon 12
Aryan   4
Jaesmin 7
Vick    13
Padukon 12
Joseph  9
Marya   10
Vicky   16
```

Comment: @marc_s: As wrote @Maximilian Mayerl - it is posible ;).

Comment: What is the point of the tally table?

Comment: You need to add a column to `@Input`, or insert the data into another temp table/table variable, as per @Maximilians answer, because there's no way in SQL Server to order e.g. the four rows with Name = 'Aryan'

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Way exists! See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT t1.name, t.n
FROM
(
    SELECT a.name, a.c, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @input AS i2 WHERE i2.Name <= a.Name) [rn]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT i.name, count(*) c
        FROM @input i
        GROUP BY i.name
    )a
)t1
JOIN @t t ON t.n <= t1.rn
WHERE t.n > t1.rn - t1.c
```

It produces desired output:

```
name     n
-------- -----------
Aryan    1
Aryan    2
Aryan    3
Aryan    4
Jaesmin  5
Jaesmin  6
Jaesmin  7
Joseph   8
Joseph   9
Marya    10
Padukon  11
Padukon  12
Vick     13
Vicky    14
Vicky    15
Vicky    16
```

Comment: Hi, it works like a charm.. but could you please explain the code

Answer (score 3):

Declare your table variable as

```
Declare  @input TABLE(_id int identity(1, 1), Name VARCHAR(8))
```

And then reqrite your query as

```
Select _id, name 
from @input
where _id % 2 <> 0
```

Comment: If I have a tally table(without disturbing the existing @input table schema) then how can i do so e.g. declare @t table(n int)
insert into @t select 1 union all select 2 union all
select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all
select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all
select 9 union all select 10 union all select 11 union all
select 12 union all select 13 union all select 14 union all
select 15 union all select 16 union all select 17 union all
select 18 union all select 19 union all select 20

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get what you are asking... could you reformulate that question?

Comment: It's [important](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/273586) to populate this temp table using `INSERT...SELECT...ORDER BY`, not `SELECT...INTO...ORDER BY`.

Comment: Yes, but what do you want to do with that tally table?

Comment: Sir, I cannot change the table schema.. but I can use a tally table ...henceforth I want to use a tally table and not the identity column

Comment: @aditi: Using @input table variable is not changing the schema. The tally table is useless

Comment: Sir, but I cannot add an identity colum.. so is there any other way to achieve the same without using tally table and identity column?

Comment: I have tried with SELECT name, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @input AS i2 WHERE i2.Name <= i1.Name) As rn
FROM @input AS i1 but not the correct answer

Comment: No, there is no other way in SQL Server 2000. You could copy your existing table to a table variable with an added identity column and use that.

Comment: @aditi: you are not adding an identity column to existing schema