# How to generate RowID in Sql server 2000 without using identity column

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

Let me frame my question ....

I have say

```
Name

A
B
C
A
D
B
```

What I want is

```
ID   Name
1    A
2    B
3    C
4    A
5    D
6    B
```

If I write 
`SELECT name, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @t AS i2 WHERE i2.Name <= i1.Name) As rn FROM @t AS i1`

it will work fine if all the names are distinct/unique...What if they are not(as in this example)

Even NEWID() does not make the trick as it varies overtime?

I am using sql server 2000...

Please help

Comment: Why not use the solution you've gotten to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490336/row-number-simulation-in-sql-server-2000)??

Comment: Also, that's for some degrees of "work fine" as you have a triangular join there, aka half a cross-join, aka rbar (row by agonizing row).

Comment: The real question is why do you need row_number at all? ie, what is the problem you're trying to solve. Then perhaps there is an alternative solution that doesn't need row_number.

Comment: Stop saying "I cannot use identity column". There are no schema changes using a temp table/table variable. if you want to use the slower triangulat COUNT join, then do so as per answers on the other question.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 ways of solving it

1.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ([ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1), name CHAR)
INSERT @t VALUES ('b')
INSERT @t VALUES ('a')
INSERT @t VALUES ('c')
INSERT @t VALUES ('b')

SELECT * FROM @t
```

2.

```
DECLARE @t2 TABLE (name CHAR)
INSERT @t2 (name) VALUES ('b')
INSERT @t2 (name) VALUES ('a')
INSERT @t2 (name) VALUES ('c')
INSERT @t2 (name) VALUES ('b')

SELECT ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b), name 
FROM (SELECT name, null b FROM @t2) temp
```

Comment: 'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name

Comment: @Apocatastasis after sqlserver 2008 it is