# Stick two tables together

Tags: sql, sqlite

Let's consider two tables:
First:

```
Id Data
1  asd
2  buu
```

And Second:
**UPD:**

```
Id Data
10  ffu
11  fffuuu
10001  asd
```

I want to get a 4-column table looking like this:

```
Id1  Data1    Id2 Data2
1     asd      10     fuu  
2     buu      11     fffuuu
-1 [any text]  10001   asd
```

(if the numbers of rows are not equal ,let's use "-1" for the id)
How to do this?

I'm using sqlite3-3.7.3.

**UPD2:**
There is no matching criteria between tables,any random matching between them will be sufficient for me.

Comment: Are the numbers in the ID column matching on purpose, or is that a coincidence of your example?

Comment: Are `Id1` and `Id2` meant to always be equal? If so, there are trivial answers. If not, then you need to be aware that tables in SQL have **no** inherent order - there's no way to say "row 1 of table 1 should match row 1 of table 2" - because the rows aren't numbered.

Comment: Yes,it was a coincidence ,the ids are not matching on porpose.I want to get a result with any random matching

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Why do you want to do this? What is your goal?

Comment: I agree this question is practically strange.I encounter the problem on another forum(non-english and not so popular),and the author doesn't want to explain his goals.My goal is to know the best answer and to help other people:)I'm  a student and just learning sql myself.

Comment: I think you need any function in SQLite like `row_number()` in T-SQL.

Comment: Not sure why you got 3 downvotes on this; this is a fair question about what you can do with SQL; unless SO is only about things that are used in the "real world" or for so-called LOB soft....

Comment: Because SQL is (however loosely) based on the relational model, and a query is essentially a specification (you tell the DBMS what you want rather than how to get it), it doesn't do 'random' and 'arbitrary' very well. This is usually a good thing :) Suggestion: rank each table by a its key then `OUTER JOIN` using ranks.

Comment: @onedaywhen: is your comment some answer to my comment as to why this is being downvoted?

Comment: as for real world... this request is exactly like the python zip() function which does parallel iteration over two sets.  e.g. I have two identical length tables - facts and labels, I want a result set/table which contains both using position rather than an external id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the id columns are unique and not null, you can "zip" your tables by:

1. Creating a row number for each row that corresponds to the
   position of the row when the table is ordered by the unique id (as
   polishchuk mentioned in his comment); and,
2. Simulating a FULL OUTER JOIN with 2 LEFT OUTER JOINS.

To demonstrate, I used two tables with differing row counts:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, data TEXT);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (NULL, 'a');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (NULL, 'b');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (NULL, 'c');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (NULL, 'd');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (NULL, 'e');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (NULL, 'f');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (NULL, 'g');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (NULL, 'h');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (NULL, 'i');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (NULL, 'j');
DELETE FROM foo WHERE data IN ('b', 'd', 'f', 'i');

CREATE TABLE bar (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, data TEXT);
INSERT INTO bar VALUES (NULL, 'a');
INSERT INTO bar VALUES (NULL, 'b');
INSERT INTO bar VALUES (NULL, 'c');
INSERT INTO bar VALUES (NULL, 'd');
INSERT INTO bar VALUES (NULL, 'e');
INSERT INTO bar VALUES (NULL, 'f');
INSERT INTO bar VALUES (NULL, 'g');
INSERT INTO bar VALUES (NULL, 'h');
INSERT INTO bar VALUES (NULL, 'i');
INSERT INTO bar VALUES (NULL, 'j');
DELETE FROM bar WHERE data IN ('a', 'b');
```

To obtain a more readable output, I then ran:

```
.headers on
.mode column
```

Then you can execute this SQL statement:

```
SELECT COALESCE(id1, -1) AS id1, data1, 
       COALESCE(id2, -1) as id2, data2 
FROM (
    SELECT ltable.rnum AS rnum, 
           ltable.id AS id1, ltable.data AS data1, 
           rtable.id AS id2, rtable.data AS data2
    FROM
        (SElECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo 
            WHERE id <= T1.id) rnum, id, data FROM foo T1
        ) ltable
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SElECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bar 
            WHERE id <= T1.id) rnum, id, data FROM bar T1
        ) rtable
        ON ltable.rnum=rtable.rnum
    UNION
    SELECT rtable.rnum AS rnum, 
           ltable.id AS id1, ltable.data AS data1, 
           rtable.id AS id2, rtable.data AS data2
    FROM
        (SElECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bar 
            WHERE id <= T1.id) rnum, id, data FROM bar T1
        ) rtable
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SElECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo 
            WHERE id <= T1.id) rnum, id, data FROM foo T1
        ) ltable
        ON ltable.rnum=rtable.rnum)
ORDER BY rnum
```

Which gives you:

```
id1         data1       id2         data2     
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           a           3           c         
3           c           4           d         
5           e           5           e         
7           g           6           f         
8           h           7           g         
10          j           8           h         
-1                      9           i         
-1                      10          j
```

This works "both ways", for example, if you invert the two tables (foo and bar), you get:

```
id1         data1       id2         data2     
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
3           c           1           a         
4           d           3           c         
5           e           5           e         
6           f           7           g         
7           g           8           h         
8           h           10          j         
9           i           -1                    
10          j           -1
```

Comment: @Noname111: Good to know; feel free to mark it as the answer if it suits you ;)

Comment: @sixfeetsix, I proposed alike solution in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490336/row-number-simulation-in-sql-server-2000