# How do I generate row number without using rownum() in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table:

```
CREATE table prd
(
prdid varchar(10)
)
insert into prd values ('prd1011'),('prd1023'),('prd4532'),('prd2341')
```

I need to return the same with rownumber without using ROWNUM() built in function.
Is that possible?

Comment: Why can't you use [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)? Is this for SQL Server 2000?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select *, (
    select count(*)
    from prd p2
    where p1.prdid >= p2.prdid
) as cnt
from prd p1
```

Answer (score 4):

You've failed to specify SQL Server version or motivation for the request.

A SQL Server 2012+ method

```
SELECT prdid,
       COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY prdid ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM prd
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/de3c2/1)

Comment: I think this should be the best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and it worked but it is working only if the prdid column is unique:

```
select prdid,
(select COUNT(*) from prd p where p.prdid >= r.prdid)rnk
from prd r order by rnk
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution for non-unique column:

```
SELECT p.prdid, p.num - t.n + 1 as num
FROM (
    SELECT p1.prdid, p1.cnt
        , (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM prd p2
            WHERE p2.prdid <= p1.prdid
        ) num
    FROM (
        SELECT p1.prdid, COUNT(*) cnt
        FROM prd p1
        GROUP BY p1.prdid
    ) p1
) p
INNER JOIN (
    select 1 n union all select 2 union all
    select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all
    select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all
    select 9 union all select 10 union all select 11 union all
    select 12 union all select 13 union all select 14 union all
    select 15 union all select 16 union all select 17 union all
    select 18 union all select 19 union all select 20
) t ON t.n <= p.cnt
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6491925/1842350).