# MSSQL equivalent of this mysql query that emulates row_number()

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

MS-SQL's row_number() can be emulate with this following query but I need MS-SQL implementation of this query.

```
 SELECT @row_number:= IF(@column_name = column_name, @row_number+1, 1) AS row_no,
 @column_name:= column_name AS column_name
 FROM db_name, (SELECT @row_number := 0, @column_name := '') AS temp
 ORDER BY column_name;
```

Comment: it's not clear what you are asking for. Do you need the MySQL version of row_number()?

Comment: I need mssql version of this mysql query, i know there is row_number() window function for achieving this and this query is somewhat equivalent to that. but i need to achieve same result without using row_number() in mssql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column_name)
FROM db_name
```

EDIT

**Without row_number()**

```
select *, (     
    select count(*)     
    from db_name p2     
    where p1.column_name >= p2.column_name ) 
as cnt from db_name p1
```

EDIT 2 according to comment of Damien

The non row_number() version only works if the content of your column_name column doesn't contain duplicates. If not there will be duplicates and skips in the row_number result column.

Comment: So you want the same functionality like my query does, but without row_number() in ms sql? May I ask why?

Comment: As described here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851527/how-do-i-generate-row-number-without-using-rownum-in-sql-server) you can do `select *, (
    select count(*)
    from db_name p2
    where p1.column_name >= p2.column_name
) as cnt
from db_name p1`

Comment: The non-`ROW_NUMBER()` one assumes that all `column_name` values are distinct. If not, you'll get duplicates and skips. It's more akin to `RANK()` than `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: Yes you are right Damien . Is this OK in you're specific case @Tushar ?

Comment: What if the column names are not distinct? Can you point me out how to implement equivalent query that "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column_name ORDER BY column_name)" does?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct MS-SQL implementation, without `row_number()`, would be more like:

```
with dn as (
      select dn.*, checksum(newid()) as rnd
      from db_name dn
     )
select dn.*,
       (select count(*)
        from dn dn2
        where dn2.column_name = dn.column_name and
              dn2.rnd < db.rnd
       ) 
from dn;
```

Of course, if an `id` column were available (one that is unique on each row), then it is better to use that:

```
select dn.*,
       (select count(*)
        from db_name dn2
        where dn2.column_name = dn.column_name and
              dn2.id < db.id
       ) 
from db_name dn;
```