# SQL mimicking analytic LEAD/LAG function with some restrictions

Tags: sql

There is a table named *test*, with one column named *amount* (number datatype).
There is no PK for this table, and amounts can be repeated.
The table's DDL is below: (created for testing purposes in Oracle 18c xe)

```
create table test (amount number(20));
insert into test values (20);
insert into test values (10);
insert into test values (30);
insert into test values (20);
insert into test values (10);
insert into test values (40);
insert into test values (15);
insert into test values (40);
```

The goal is to mimick the LEAD analytical function results ordered by amount, but no analytic (incl. ranking and window functions) can be used. PSM (incl MYSQL stored features, PL/SQL, T-SQL etc.) or some kind of identity tables can neither be used.

The desired output is shown in *lead_rows_analytic_amount* column:

```
select 
amount,
lead(amount) over (order by amount) as lead_rows_analytic_amount
from test t1;
```

```
actual result:
amount  lead_rows_analytic_amount
10      10
10      15
15      20
20      20
20      30
30      40
40      40
40
```

What are some elegant ways to achieve the result taking into account the restrictions set?
The DB is irrelevant here, if the restrictions apply.

I am attaching a stupidly clumsy and direct solution I came up with, but the goal is to get something more elegant (ignoring the performance).

```
with initial_rn as (
select
 amount,t1.rowid,
 ( select count (*)
    from test t2
    where
      t1.amount >= t2.amount
 ) as rn
from test t1
)
,prep_table as (
select t1.*,nvl2(repeating_rn,1,0) as repeating_rn_tag,
nvl(( SELECT max(rn)
FROM initial_rn t2
where t2.rn < t1.rn
),0) AS lag_rn
from initial_rn t1
left join (select rn as repeating_rn
from initial_rn
group by rn
having count(*) > 1) t2 on t1.rn = t2.repeating_rn
)
,final_rn as (
select t1.amount,case when repeating_rn_tag = 0 then rn else lag_rn + 
( select count (*)
    from prep_table t2
    where
      t1.rowid >= t2.rowid and t1.repeating_rn_tag = 1 and t2.repeating_rn_tag = 1 and t1.rn = t2.rn
      )
      end as final_rn
from prep_table t1
)


select t1.*,
lead(amount) over (order by amount) as lead_rows_analytic_amount,
(select min(amount)
from test t2
where t2.amount > t1.amount
) as lead_range_amount,
(SELECT MIN(amount)
FROM final_rn t2
where t2.final_rn > t1.final_rn
) AS lead_amount
from final_rn t1 
order by amount
;
```

Comment: Might be proved wrong but this is likely not possible using "simple" set logic sinse there are duplicate values in a set that's inherently unordered.

Comment: You are not wrong in the sense that they are unordered, but Oracle somehow orders them indetermenistically when LEAD function is used. One way to do it is by mimicking row_number() function first, which can be mimicked using an identity support table as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851527/how-do-i-generate-row-number-without-using-rownum-in-sql-server/18852121#18852121

Comment: I’m wondering what the purpose of this question is? Can you name a DB where these restrictions apply and, if not, why are you trying to come up with a solution to a problem that doesn’t involve using the functionality the DB provides to help you solve this class of problem?

Comment: @NickW, the question is probably half-valid for ancient DB's like Sybase IQ 15.1 which lack some analytic functions as lead,last_value and row_number, but probably some alternatives are always possible using more available analytic functions there. But the question itself is purely theoretical and out of curiosity of how things can work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, you can use:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN LEVEL = 1 THEN amount ELSE PRIOR amount END AS amount,
       CASE WHEN LEVEL = 1 THEN NULL   ELSE amount       END AS lead_amount
FROM   (
  SELECT amount,
         ROWNUM AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT amount
    FROM   test
    ORDER BY amount
  )
)
WHERE LEVEL = 2
OR    LEVEL = 1 AND CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR rn + 1 = rn
```

More generally, you can use:

```sql
WITH ordered_amounts (amount) AS (
  SELECT amount
  FROM   test
  ORDER BY amount
),
indexed_amounts (amount, idx) AS (
  SELECT amount,
         ROWNUM -- Or any function that gives sequentially increasing values
  FROM   ordered_amounts
)
SELECT i.amount,
       nxt.amount AS lead_amount
FROM   indexed_amounts i
       LEFT OUTER JOIN indexed_amounts nxt
       ON (i.idx + 1 = nxt.idx)
```

Which, for the sample data, both output:

> | AMOUNT | LEAD_AMOUNT |
> | --- | --- |
> | 10 | 10 |
> | 10 | 15 |
> | 15 | 20 |
> | 20 | 20 |
> | 20 | 30 |
> | 30 | 40 |
> | 40 | 40 |
> | 40 | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=da4b281da5dec2f1fe2c9f53e69f1dbc)*

Comment: @Stu Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, I thought rownum shows the rowid ordering only, and cannot take new values for each derived view.  The hierachical solution is probably very good, though cant really estimate the magnitude.

Comment: @4yz `ROWNUM` will give a sequential numbering to the rows in the order they are processed. The first step used in the query is to order the rows and then the second step is to assign a `ROWNUM` so, in this case, because it is being pre-ordered, the increasing `ROWNUM` value will correlate with the increasing magnitude of the `amount` column.

Comment: Thanks, the rownum solution is pretty clear for me. I was referring to the first solution which is something I havent worked with (hierachical queries).

Comment: The hierarchical query uses exactly the same theory as the second query; it orders the rows then numbers the (ordered) rows and then connects each row to the next row in the result set (and then stops recursing the hierarchy). The only thing that needs special handling is the last row in the result set as it won't have anything to connect to but that is done by finding the only level 1 row that is a leaf in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so just throwing this out there as something you *could* do, using JSON functionality (support exists in most RDBMS)

This is SQL server syntax:

```
with v as (
    select *
    from OpenJson(
        (select Concat('[',String_Agg(amount,',') 
            within group (order by amount),']')from test)
        )
)
select value, (
    select value 
    from v v2 
    where v2.[key]=v.[key]+1
 ) as lead_rows_analytic_amount
from v
```

[Example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c67e803aacdfe757f6e4dba5508f1bfb)

Comment: Thanks, I will need to test the functionality, but isnt "within group" clause implying its analytic function?

Comment: To my knowledge it's not classed as an analytic function, you might be arguing semantics; with a duplicate set of rows, ultimately there has to be some method of determining order.

Comment: Thanks, not arguing

Comment: By the same criteria using *rownum* in Oracle is not ANSI SQL but provides the exact functionality of *row_number*

Comment: Yes, the thing is I have had some wrong knowledge about how rownum works, and didnt expect it to be a complete alternative of row_number. If i knew, I probably specified it as a restricted functionality, when specifying my initial question, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

To contribute to this wonderful collection of solutions how to avoid window functions, I feel it's worth mention Oracle `model` clause:

```sql
with test as (
  select column_value as amount
  from table(sys.ku$_vcnt(20,10,30,20,10,40,15,40)) -- or your table, I'm just lazy to create fiddle
)
select amount, lead_amount
from (
  select *
  from (select amount, 0 as lead_amount from test order by amount)
  model
    dimension by (rownum as rn)
    measures (amount, lead_amount)
    rules (amount[any] = amount[cv(rn)], lead_amount[any] = amount[cv(rn) + 1])
)
order by amount
```

(Not sure if it is helpful for you, compared with window functions.)

Comment: Thanks, it is helpful (for me at least) in getting some clues to understand how the model clause actually works, though the solution itself relies on rownum.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a primary key (any table should have):

```
select a.*, (select min(r.amount)
             from #test r
             where ((r.id <> a.id and r.amount > a.amount) 
                    OR 
                    (r.id > a.id and r.amount=a.amount)
                    )
            ) as NextVal
from #test a
order by a.amount, a.id
```